# Java: Validating a string

Tags: java, string, methods, notnull

So I am working on a project in java and I have just a quick question.

I have a method that is receiving a string and I want to strip out the spaces and check that is is not empty. So far I have the below in place however it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
public static Boolean isValid(String s) {
    s.replace(" ", "");
    if (s == ""){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :) 
Ta

Comment: instead of `s == ""` use `"".equals(s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have forgot the assignment for `s.replace(" ","")`. Store that in a variable, e.g.

```
x = s.replace(" ","");
```

For string comparison use `.equals()` method instead of `==`

Answer (score 6):

You can try with this:

```
public static Boolean isValid(String s) {
    return (!s.trim().isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: Actually, this does only remove the leading and trailing spaces. `s.replace()` will also replace the spaces in the middle of the string.

Comment: @Magnilex if there is a white space in the middle of the string, then there are non-whitespace chars in the string... the result is the same!

Comment: Yes, of course. You are correct. +1 for the most elegant solution.

Comment: I agree that this is the most elegant solution and the one that should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code as well :

`newString=myString.replaceAll("\\s+","");` 
This removes one or more spaces in between Strings as well as leading and trailing whitespaces

Use : `myString.trim()` to remove only leading and trailing whitespaces

and then `newString.isEmpty()`

You should use `.equals()` to compare Strings

Answer (score 1):

When you're comparing strings, use `.equals()`.
Its only in artihmetic expressions you use the `==` sign

TO check whether your string is empty use the `.isEmpty()` function

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the assignment:

```
s = s.replace(" ", "");
```

EDIT:
for the comments stating that == is not working. I wanted to say that it does work for Java 7

Answer (score 1):

replaceAll() method supports regular expressions as well as isEmpty() is already there in String class so we can reuse it and is safer to use here.

simply use like this:

```
public static Boolean isValid(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    } 
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between equals and == incase of String comparison is well explained in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

value of s.replace() should be assigned to itself or some other variable.